# Why qemu with kvm enabled can boot kernel even if identity page map is not set correctly?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

In the early stages of boot process, kernel need identity mapped page setup when [switching gdt](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ed30b147e1f6e396e70a52dbb6c7d66befedd786/arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S#L133-L137) as code [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ed30b147e1f6e396e70a52dbb6c7d66befedd786/arch/x86/kernel/head64.c#L98-L138) implies. That's why the first few entries of `early_dynamic_pgts` are set to map the kernel text range [_text, _end]. But as we discussed about the role of the first few entries of early_dynamic_pgts, we delete [them](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/ed30b147e1f6e396e70a52dbb6c7d66befedd786/arch/x86/kernel/head64.c#L98-L138) and recompile the kernel, then test it on qemu. Without '--enable-kvm' option the kernel won't boot as we expected, but with '--enable-kvm' option on, the kernel boot and everything runs well, really to our surprise.

So I guess there are something under the hood done by kvm, which doesn't obey the rules of how a real physical machine behaves. Can anyone confirm what we've observed? Any details or explanation would be really appreciated!

Comment: BTW, Bochs & Vmware are also [reported](https://github.com/0xAX/linux-insides/issues/544) to boot correctly

Comment: @jww: The question is perfectly about *programming*. It talks about QEMU only in relation with running the code created.

Comment: @Tsyvarev - Ack, thanks.